# After employer change, do I have to go to US Embassy for visa stamping again?

Tags: working-visas, indian-citizens, h1-visa

I got my H1B Visa stamped last year and it is (was?) valid till 2017. It was through my earlier employer ABC. I have changed the job and my new employer got my Visa transferred. Now, it is valid till 2016 (so not 2017 anymore).

I am going back for vacation. My colleagues told me that I need to go to US embassy to get the Visa stamped as I have changed the employer. I talked regarding this with the employer. My employer in turn contacted their attorney. I got the reply that I don't need to go to Embassy for stamping. He said that when I will come back then at port of entry my Visa (and I-94) will be updated.

I am totally confused who is right. Can you guys please let me know, do I need to go for stamping?

Comment: The lawyer probably knows the law better than your colleagues.  Have you looked on the website of the USCIS?

Comment: I looked, but could not got any clue at all.

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/322/h1b-green-card-permanent-residency-process-with-employer-change

Answer (score 2):

Online sites like [immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/h1b/h1-transfer.html) state that you ONLY need to get a new visa stamp if your current one has expired, where USCIS might also ask you to exit the country and come back in.

However, if your visa stamp is current and not expired, you don't need a new stamp.

[More information is available in their FAQ](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/h1b/h1-visa-transfer-faq.html).

Comment: Furthermore, if your visa stamp is expired, but you do not plan to leave the US and then return in H1B status, you do not need a new stamp.  Therefore, you will have to leave the country to get a new visa stamp -- because you only require a new visa stamp if you are leaving the country.